# SQL syntax for removing a specific row [time] from a specific group [symbol]

Tags: sql, presto

I'm running up against the edge of my SQL Query knowledge and could use a point in the right direction. (I am using Presto, but ideally that shouldn't matter because Presto uses common SQL syntax.)

**What I would like to do is always exclude the 9:31:00 [QuoteTime] ONLY on the 'VIX' Symbol. If possible, I would only like to exclude the 9:31:00 VIX [QuoteTime] row only IF the [Bid] AND [Ask] are 0.**

I have looked into the HAVING clause as an alternative/addition to the WHERE clause. I was not successful in integrating this to my query.

I have looked into the LIKE clause in an effort to find the 9:31:00 time. I'm also concerned about my ability to write this efficiently.

My struggle is combining them to create the correct and *most efficient* query.

**Here is my data:**

```
+---------------+--------+---------+---------+
| QuoteTime     | Symbol |   Bid   |   Ask   |
+---------------+--------+---------+---------+
| 09:31:00      | VIX    |       0 |       0 |
| 09:32:00      | VIX    |   13.24 |   13.24 |
| 09:33:00      | VIX    |   13.21 |   13.21 |
| 09:31:00      | SPX    | 2889.36 | 2894.18 |
| 09:32:00      | SPX    | 2889.15 | 2892.99 |
| 09:33:00      | SPX    | 2889.89 | 2892.71 |
| 09:31:00      | NDX    | 7616.64 | 7616.64 |
| 09:32:00      | NDX    | 7612.13 | 7612.13 |
| 09:33:00      | NDX    | 7613.32 | 7613.32 |
+---------------+--------+---------+---------+
```

**Here is my current query:**

```
SELECT QuoteTime, Symbol, ((Bid+Ask)/2) as MidPoint 
FROM schema.tablename 
WHERE (Symbol IN ('SPX', 'VIX'))
```

Below is my nuclear option. I don't like it because it may (unbeknownst to me) remove other rows which contain 0s on other symbols at other times:

```
SELECT QuoteTime, Symbol, ((Bid+Ask)/2) as MidPoint 
FROM schema.tablename 
WHERE (Symbol IN ('SPX', 'VIX')) AND Bid != 0 AND Ask != 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to select all rows for symbols 'SPX' and 'VIX', but exclude  9:31:00 - VIX - 0 - 0. There are several ways to express this. One way has been shown in fa06's answer.

```
SELECT quotetime, symbol, ((bid+ask)/2) as midpoint 
FROM schema.tablename 
WHERE symbol in ('SPX', 'VIX')
AND (quotetime, symbol, bid, ask) NOT IN ((time '09:31', 'VIX', 0, 0));
```

*(EDIT: You say that this doesn't work for you. It may be that presto doesn't yet support the `IN` clause with tuples.)*

Another is:

```
SELECT quotetime, symbol, ((bid+ask)/2) as midpoint 
FROM schema.tablename 
WHERE symbol IN ('SPX', 'VIX')
AND (quote_time <> time '09:31' OR symbol <> 'VIX' OR bid <> 0 OR ask <> 0);
```

Another is:

```
SELECT quotetime, symbol, ((bid+ask)/2) as midpoint 
FROM schema.tablename 
WHERE symbol IN ('SPX', 'VIX')
AND NOT (quote_time = time '09:31' AND symbol = 'VIX' AND bid = 0 AND ask = 0);
```

(If one of the columns can be null then you must consider this in the query, too. E.g. `(ask <> 0 OR ask IS NULL)`.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and simplification. `AND NOT` worked best for me here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
SELECT QuoteTime, Symbol, ((Bid+Ask)/2) as MidPoint 
FROM schema.tablename 
WHERE (QuoteTime, Symbol,Bid,Ask) not in (('09:31:00','VIX',0,0))
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am attempting, but having difficulty - it seems because I must have an `IN` and a `NOT IN` in the same query. (I have adjusted my data table above to reflect that there are more than just the two symbols.)

Comment: @Daniel Sims: How does this matter? Do you want to exclude symbols other than 'SPX' and 'VIX' from your result, too?

Comment: Correct, I want to only select SPX and VIX - and leave NDX out.

Comment: @Daniel Sims: Okay, that was not clear from your request. Then you simply have to add the condition that you want to see those two symbols. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I apologize for my non-clarity. I was not able to get `NOT IN` to work for some reason. I will continue to tinker with it for the future though. I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: @Daniel Sims: It may be that presto doesn't support `[NOT] IN` for tuples. Some DBMS do, others don't.